# API call checking if certain data is retrieved

Tags: python, api

I am performing 100 API calls on 100 different cities and when it is called it usually comes in the form :

```
{'data': {'aqi': 13,
          'attributions': [{'name': 'Air Quality Ontario - the Ontario '
                                    'Ministry of the Environment and Climate '
                                    'Change',
                            'url': 'http://www.airqualityontario.com/'},
                           {'name': 'World Air Quality Index Project',
                            'url': 'https://waqi.info/'}],
          'city': {'geo': [43.653226, -79.3831843],
                   'name': 'Toronto',
                   'url': 'https://aqicn.org/city/toronto'},
          'debug': {'sync': '2019-06-04T15:37:48+09:00'},
          'dominentpol': 'pm25',
          'iaqi': {'co': {'v': 1.7},
                   'no2': {'v': 15.2},
                   'o3': {'v': 8.8},
                   'p': {'v': 1018.3},
                   'pm25': {'v': 13},
                   'so2': {'v': 0.2},
                   't': {'v': 11.6},
                   'w': {'v': 0.2}},
          'idx': 5914,
 'status': 'ok'}
```

However in ['data']['iaqi'] sometime it lacks one of co, no2, o3,etc... while looping through 100 cities and performing api calls I want to check if each of them are present and append "na" if it is not present.

I am doing try and except like this:

```
cities = []
aqi = []


# 5 pollutants used to calculate AQI
CO = []
NO2 = []
SO2 = []
pm25 = []


for city in canadian_cities:
    city_name = city
    url = f'https://api.waqi.info/feed/{city}/?token={api_key}'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    if (response["status"] == "ok"):
        # sometime aqi might not be a number, exclude them

        print("yes")
        if (isinstance(response["data"]["aqi"], int)):
            # append aqi and city name to appropriate list
            aqi.append(response["data"]["aqi"])
            cities.append(city)

            # append pollutants individually
            try:
                CO.append(response["data"]["iaqi"]["co"]["v"])
            except:
                CO.append("na")
            try:
                NO2.append(response["data"]["iaqi"]["no2"]["v"])
            except:
                NO2.append("na")
            try:
                SO2.append(response["data"]["iaqi"]["o3"]["v"])
            except:
                SO2.append("na")
            pm25.append(response["data"]["iaqi"]["pm25"]["v"])
```

This works perfectly fine however does not seem efficient, I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping your polutants as separate lists, keep a dictionary like this:

```
polutants = {"co":[],"no2":[],"so2":[],"pm25":[]}
```

If you make sure your keys match what you would expect from the API you can now do this:

```
for item in polutants.keys():
   if item in response["data"]["iaqi"].keys():
      polutants[item].append(response["data"]["iaqi"][item])
   else:
      polutants[item].append('na')
```

but your way is perfectly fine too to be honest.

Comment: oh haha yup but I want to make it cleaner. thanks for the help! this seems much cleaner.

Comment: The first line can also be replaced with `polutants = defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `get` method instead 
eg:

```
<your_variable>.append(data["iaqi"].get("co",data["iaqi"]).get("v","na"))
```

Answer (score 0):

choosing better data structures can make it way better

```
from collections import defaultdict
cities = defaultdict(dict)
data_points = ["co", "no2", "o3", "pm25"]

for city in canadian_cities:
    url = f'https://api.waqi.info/feed/{city}/?token={api_key}'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    if (response["status"] == "ok"):
        # sometime aqi might not be a number, exclude them
        print("yes")
        if (isinstance(response["data"]["aqi"], int)):
            # append aqi and city name to appropriate list
            cities[city]['aqi'] = response["data"]["aqi"]
            for data_point in data_points:
                cities[city][data_point] = response["data"]["iaqi"].get(data_point, dict()).get("v", "na")

print(cities)
```

I would even go bit further and refactor it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

cities = defaultdict(dict)
data_points = ['aqi', "co", "no2", "o3", "pm25"]
defaults = ['na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na']
AQI = namedtuple('AQI', field_names=data_points, defaults=defaults)

def get_data(city):
    url = f'https://api.waqi.info/feed/{city}/?token={api_key}'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    if response["status"] == "ok":
        return response

def parse_json(data):
    raw_data = {key:value['v'] for key, value in data["iaqi"].items() if key in data_points[1:]}
    raw_data['aqi'] = data["aqi"]
    return AQI(**raw_data)

for city in canadian_cities:
    data = get_data(city)
    if data and isinstance(data["data"]["aqi"], int):
        cities[city] = parse_json(data=data["data"])
print(cities)
```